# Create a text label with filtered results from DT

Tags: r, label, shiny, dt

In my application I enter a name and a year and return filtered data-set in screen.
Code from application server.R file is listed below:

```
# Get raw data
getTable <- function(df, reaction){
nameSearch = capitalize(tolower(reaction$nameSearch))
new_df <- subset(df, grepl(nameSearch, Name))
year <- reaction$year
indices <- which((new_df$Year >= year[1] & new_df$Year <= year[2]))
new_df <- new_df[indices,-1]
new_df$region <- toupper(new_df$region)
colnames(new_df) <- c("City", "Gender", "Year", "Name", "Frequency")
return(new_df)
}
```

I need to print in a label below the table the sum of all frequencies for the searched name

I mean if I search for John in 2012 and table returned is as shown in figure :

[image]

I need some label with text: "**There are 27 people with name John for 2012**" under the table to be shown

Please help in this task

Regards